# How to clean php output in OS X

Tags: php, macos, terminal

Everytime I type the php in my terminal I get this output:

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_gd2.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_gd2.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

How to I clean this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have added this in comment but i don't have enough privilege to comment so posting it here.

I have no experience on handling php on OS X, have only read about it.

I have tried to search for issue your facing and found an article online related to PHP, APACHE and Drupal. Here is the [link](http://drupal7demo.webel.com.au/node/2392)

Search the page with following error

usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_gd2.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_gd2.dll

Hope this helps you

Comment: Awesome. The problem was so stupid. I only had to comment the extension that was not being found in php ini configuration file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment out "php_gd2.dll" from your php.ini, because any .dll files are only for windows and not for mac OS.